# Find out what port Django instance is running on?

Tags: django, port

Is there any way to find out what port a Django instance is listening on from within the code?

Comment: Within Django code, or from an external process (e.g. command line)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the info through the HttpRequest. Checkout the Django Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/).

This can be accessed through the META attribute which is a dictionary containing the HTTP header info.

Example:

```
def someView(request):
    #Try printing to screen
    print request.META['SERVER_PORT']
    ...
    return(response)
```

Comment: Does `SERVER_PORT` exist reliably, or is there a danger that it will sometimes be absent?

Comment: well, as far as I can tell it will work fine on a development server. I have not tried to use it running under Apache. I would write a bit of test code to double check though. Otherwise, I'm not sure how else you would find out without going through the request object.

Comment: What if you're not in a view?

Comment: @johnboiles, where else would you be that you would need to know the port? If you need it in a template you can just pass the port info along.

Comment: in my case, i want to use the port number in a file name created at startup. the port comes from the uwsgi command line.

Comment: @mARK you can take SERVER_PORT from the uwsgi environment [parameter](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application) (usually 'env').

Answer (score 4):

maybe `request.META['SERVER_PORT']`

or are you not in a view?

Comment: Is there a solution when I am not in a view?

Answer (score 3):

I found this might be helpful if you need to know the port number or IP address out of the view(in models.py for example.)

```
import sys
import socket
logger.error(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())+"----"+sys.argv[-1])
```

This will give you an output like below:

```
192.168.1.222----0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: @utapyngo This is the solution when you are not in a view.

Comment: You can never be sure that the port to run was provided via command arguments (sys.argv)

Answer (score 2):

Request's have a method build in specifically for this.

```
def someView(request):
    print(request.get_port())
```